# Confusion regarding MongoDb schema in mongooseJs. How to improve it?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've two documents here.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
        username: {
          type: String,
          validate: [required,"Username is required"],
          index: {unique: true}
        },
        email: {
            type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Email,
            validate: [required, 'Email required'],
            index: { unique: true }
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            validate: [required, 'Password required'],
        },
        socialauth:{
          type:[]
        },

        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            'default': Date.now
        }
    });
```

UserTwitterSchema:

```
var UserTrwitterSchema = new Schema({

  authToken: {
      type: String,
      validate: [required,"authToken is required"],
      index: {unique: true}
    },

  authSecret: {
      type: String,
      validate: [required,"authSecret is required"],
      index: {unique: true}
    },
  apiKey: {
        type: String,
        validate: [required, 'Api Key is required'],
    }, 
});
```

The confusion I've here is this:
Well, should I use apiKey or do a `user :ObjectId,` in place of that. User would be the foreign key here. Or do both? What would be least expensive when it comes to querying data? 
I've gone with apiKey here and have done the same with all my other schemas. Just wanted a second opinion as this is something completely different from how I created Relational DB.

Comment: what kind of queries are you doing? also, is UserTwitter a separate document to User?

Comment: What kind of queries are you doing?

Answer (score 0):

I would not create a speparate twitter schema if you plan to accept users with other credentials (facebook....)

Instead I would create a profiles collection with type and credentials as unique key and store user data (age,bio etc) in the users ollection.

```
profile = {
 _id : {type : "email", username : "Justin"},
 creds : {email : "foo@bar.com", pw : "hash"),
 user_id : ObjectId(xys)
}

profile2 = {
 _id : {type : "twitter", username : "JustinBieber"},
 creds : {token : "fatoken", secret : "hash" , key : "key"),
 user_id : ObjectId(xys)
```

}

and users look like:

```
user = {
 _id : ObjectId(xys),
 bio : "really young guy",
 born : date(March 1, 1994)
 ...
}
```